# Shiny conditionalpanel not evaluating at startup

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I'm using conditionalpanels to build up my Shiny app dynamically. It seems that the condition the panel is based on is not evaluated at startup. The panel is visible by default, and only disappears after some actions. The panel is visible, even though the condition is not met (input.select1.length = 0, which is less than 1...).

Minimal working example:

Server.R:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session){
  output$selectInput1 <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
      inputId = "select1",
      label = "Select",
      choices = c('1','2','3'),
      selected = NULL,
      multiple = TRUE
    )
  })
})
```

UI.R:

```
dashboardPage(
  title = "",

  ## Header content + dropdownMenu
  dashboardHeader(
    title = tags$b(""),
    titleWidth = 250
  ),

  ## Sidebar content
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 250,
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "tabs",
      menuItem("tab1", tabName = "tab", icon = icon("table"))
    )
  ),

  ## Body content
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "tab",
        div(
          div(
            style="float: left; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; width: 350px; background-color: #F4F4F4; height: calc(100vh - 50px) !important;",
            uiOutput('selectInput1')
          ),
          div(
            conditionalPanel(
              condition = "input.select1.length > 1",
              p('hi')
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Right click on page and click `inspect` you will see that it complains when you evaluate `input.select1.length`. It doesnt seem to be the proper command. Try using `jQuery` https://api.jquery.com/length/

Comment: Thx @PorkChop. I changed it to: conditionalPanel(
              condition = "typeof input.select1.length !== 'undefined'",
              conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.select1.length > 0",
                p('hi')
              )
            ) but still the same error. What would be the first condition in order to not evaluate the second?

Comment: Its probably easier for u to create another `renderUI`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @porkchop pointed out, you can create the condition in the renderUI function of `server.R`:

Server.R:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session){
  output$selectInput1 <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
      inputId = "select1",
      label = "Select",
      choices = c('1','2','3'),
      selected = NULL,
      multiple = TRUE
    )
  })
  output$panel1 <- renderUI({
    if(!is.null(input$select1) && length(input$select1) > 0){
      condition1 = 'true'
    } else {
      condition1 = 'false'
    }
    conditionalPanel(
      condition1,
      p('hi')
    )
  })
})
```

UI.R:

```
dashboardPage(
  title = "",

  ## Header content + dropdownMenu
  dashboardHeader(
    title = tags$b(""),
    titleWidth = 250
  ),

  ## Sidebar content
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 250,
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "tabs",
      menuItem("tab1", tabName = "tab", icon = icon("table"))
    )
  ),

  ## Body content
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "tab",
        div(
          div(
            style="float: left; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; width: 350px; background-color: #F4F4F4; height: calc(100vh - 50px) !important;",
            uiOutput('selectInput1')
          ),
          div(
            uiOutput('panel1')
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```